# Expo Location.getCurrentPositionAsync does not work on android build

Tags: expo

i am currently using expo-location to get the users current position. It is working on Expo Go for both Android and IOS but when a create a build to post on the stores, I get the current location on IOS but on Android I am stuck in loading.

Can someone help me out?

Here is my code:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const[location,setLocation]=useState(null);

const getLocationAsync = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
        let { status,canAskAgain } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();

      if (!canAskAgain || status === "denied") {
        Alert.alert("Location Permission","",[
          {text: 'Go to Settings', onPress: ()=>{
            Linking.openSettings();
            navigation.goBack();
          }},
        ],
        { cancelable: false })
        setLoading(false);
          return;
        }else if (status !== 'granted') {
        await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});

      const oneDegreeOfLongitudeInMeters = 111.32 * 1000;
      const circumference = (40075 / 360) * 1000;
        
      setLocation(prevState=>{
        return{
          latitude:location.coords.latitude
          ,longitude:location.coords.longitude
          ,latitudeDelta:200 * (1 / (Math.cos(location.coords.latitude) * circumference)),
          longitudeDelta:(200 / oneDegreeOfLongitudeInMeters)
        }})

      setLoading(false);
      }

      useEffect(()=>{
        getLocationAsync();
      },[])
```

Here is app.config.js as requested in the comments:

```
export default {
  "expo": {
    "name": "App Name",
    "owner":"App Owner",
    "scheme":"App Scheme",
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "compileSdkVersion": 33,
            "targetSdkVersion": 33,
            "buildToolsVersion": "31.0.0"
          },
          "ios": {
            "deploymentTarget": "13.0",
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          }
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-location",
        {
          "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "Allow App to use your location"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "slug": "App slug",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "App icon",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "App Splash",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#0a0a0a"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier":"App bundle identifier",
      "buildNumber":"1.0.14",
      "googleServicesFile": process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST,
      "config":{
        "googleMapsApiKey":process.env.IOS_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "App bundle identifier",
      "versionCode": 14,
      "googleServicesFile": process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON,
      "config":{
        "googleMaps":{
          "apiKey":process.env.STORE_ANDROID_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
        }
      },
      "permissions":["ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION","ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION","FOREGROUND_SERVICE"]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png",
      "config":{
        "firebase":{
          "apiKey": process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
          "authDomain": process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
          "projectId": process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
          "storageBucket": process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
          "messagingSenderId": process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
          "appId": process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
          "measurementId":process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
        }
      }
    },
    "extra": {
      firebaseApiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
      firebaseAuthDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
      firebaseProjectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      firebaseStorageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
      firebaseMessagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
      firebaseAppId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
      firebaseMeasurementId:process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "EAS project ID"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Kindly include the permissions you've specified in the 'app.json' configuration file for your application.

Comment: @HamidAsiabari i have added app.config.js to the question above. thank you

Answer (score 0):

To enable background location features in Android, make sure you've added the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission. Additionally, when requesting this permission, you must also request either ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, both of which should already be added to your Android permissions. Your Android permissions should look like this:

```
"permissions": ["ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION", "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION", "FOREGROUND_SERVICE", "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"]
```

Moreover, update your expo-location configuration as follows:

```
 [
 "expo-location",
  {
  "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "Allow App to use your location",
  "isAndroidBackgroundLocationEnabled": "Allow App to use your location in the background"
  }
 ]
```

As far as I recall, Expo's expo-location library encountered issues with older Android versions. I recommend testing your app on older Android versions, such as Android 9, because Android's permission system has undergone significant changes in various updates.

Please let me know if you encounter any issues or have further questions.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but in my app i do not require background location, therefore why i dont need the background location permission